# Webview can't load url in Genymotion

Tags: networking, webview, emulation, genymotion

I installed Genymotion to help test my web based apps. It turns out that apps like play store and search and also the browser can access the internet(on my host PC) but the webview in my app can't? Whats the reason, I looked for similar questions and tried their solutions, but did not get the solution. Please explain whats the problem and how to get around it. Help really appreciated